# Fabric js Image Filters

Tags: fabricjs

Hello i am trying to create img filter there are Range input sliders from which user select filter value and then applied to selected image object its working but every time input changes it added a new filter and multiply how can i resolve this issue below is my code:

```
  $('.img-fillter-controller .range-field').on("change", "input", function () {

    t = $(this).data("filter");
    v = $(this).val();
    o = activeCanvas.getActiveObject();
    switch(t) {

        case 'brightness':
              f = new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness({brightness: v/100 });
              applyImgFilter(f);
              return;
        case 'saturation':

              return;
        case 'contrast':

              return;
        case 'blur':

              return;
        case 'exposure':

              return;
        case 'colorify':

              return;
        case 'hue':




    }   
});

function applyImgFilter(f) {
    o.filters.push(f);
    o.applyFilters();
    activeCanvas.renderAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For apply filter properly  on image, we need to fix filter index or can say that assign filter by static index.

You should replace This funciton :

```
function applyImgFilter(f) {
  o.filters.push(f);
  o.applyFilters();
  activeCanvas.renderAll();
}
```

With New funciton :

```
function applyImgFilter(f) {
  o.filters[0] = f
  o.applyFilters();
  activeCanvas.renderAll();
}
```